# Redirect to admin after login - Django

Tags: django

I am trying to redirect the user after login to their appropriate login pages according to their policy.

If the user is a staff then after login the user should be redirected to admin page so on.

I have the following contents.

In my **settings.py**:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

LOGIN_URL=reverse_lazy('login')
LOGOUT_URL=reverse_lazy('logout')
```

My apps **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^login/$', authy_views.log_me_in, name="login"),
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
```

`log_me_in` is a custom login view that uses `AuthenticationForm`.

My custom login view **authy_me.views.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login as auth_login
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def log_me_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user.is_active:
            if user.is_staff and not has_2fa(user):
                logger.info('is staff but does not have 2FA, redirecting to Authy account creator')
                return redirect('%s?next=/admin/' % settings.LOGIN_URL)
            elif user.is_staff and has_2fa(user):
                logger.info("is staff and 2FA enabled redirecting to Authy verification")
                return redirect('2fa')
            elif not request.user.is_staff and not has_2fa(user):
                logger.info('is not staff and does not have 2FA')
         else:
             login(request, user)
             return redirect('/')

    defaults = {
        'authentication_form': AuthenticationForm,
        'template_name': 'login.html',
    }

    return auth_login(request, **defaults)
```

The **problem**:

Now when I try to login with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/` I get the custom login screen, after authenticating myself and the conditions for being staff & no 2fa is satisfied the url changes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/admin/` and nothing happens. Now using the new url if I try to login again nothing happens, it authenticates and stays there.

Any idea on how to get over this?

Comment: In `if user.is_staff and not has_2fa(user):`, why do you want to redirect to `settings.LOGIN_URL`? Isn't that the url you are on? Why do you want to `login(request, user)` when the user is not active?

Comment: Oh. Let me check it.

Comment: SO you mean to say i should just put `redirect('?next=/admin/')`?

Comment: or just `redirect('/admin/')`

Comment: OK so if I put `redirect('?next=/admin/')` nothing changes, the url is the same as mentioned in the question but when I change `redired('/admin/')` I get the url as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/` and goes to the login page again.

Comment: You don't login the user in the `if user.is_staff and not has_2fa(user):` block, so I'm not surprised you are being redirected back to the login page.

Comment: You suggest putting `login(request, user)` before redirecting it?

Comment: If you want to login an active staff member that does not have 2fa, then yes, you need to  call `login(request, user)`.

Comment: It works if I put `redirect('\admin\')`. Thanks. If you post the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block has a couple of issues:

```
if user.is_staff and not has_2fa(user):
    logger.info('is staff but does not have 2FA, redirecting to Authy account creator')
    return redirect('%s?next=/admin/' % settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

Firstly, you want to log the user in here, but you haven't called `login(request, user)`.

Secondly, it doesn't make sense to redirect back to the `LOGIN_URL` again.